# How can a function check which major mode is enabled?

Tags: major-mode

The accepted answer to [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20114/how-to-define-mode-specific-functions) says:

> When the function is invoked, it can test the current mode and do something appropriate. For example, for some modes, or all modes except some modes, it can be a no-op or it can raise an error.

How can this be done?

Comment: The answer showing `derived-mode-p` is the correct answer in most circumstances.  You would only test `major-mode` directly in cases where you explicitly wished to exclude derived modes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inspect the value of the variable `major-mode`.  From the docs:

> Symbol for current buffer’s major mode.
> The default value (normally ‘fundamental-mode’) affects new buffers.
> A value of nil means to use the current buffer’s major mode, provided
> it is not marked as "special".

Example:

```
(defun example ()
  (cond ((eq major-mode 'foo-mode) (foo))
        ((eq major-mode 'bar-mode) (bar))))
```

Comment: Could you give an example of a function that executes a function foo if the major is foo-mode and executes bar if in bar-mode?

Comment: Edited to give such an example

Answer (score 2):

[Fran's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/69514/38983) is perfectly acceptable but it may be worth bringing up a point made by [Bozhidar Batsov, on Emacs Redux](https://emacsredux.com/blog/2020/06/14/checking-the-major-mode-in-emacs-lisp/):

> [...] You’re doing an exact match for a particular mode, but major modes can be inherited by other modes. Consider `clojure-mode` - it’s the parent of modes like `clojurescript-mode` and `clojurec-mode`, and it inherits from `prog-mode`.

> Enter `derived-mode-p`:
>
> ```
> ;; Assuming the current major mode is clojurescript-mode
>
> (derived-mode-p 'clojurescript-mode)
> ;; => t
>
> (derived-mode-p 'clojure-mode)
> ;; => t
>
> (derived-mode-p 'prog-mode)
> ;; => t
> ```

From https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Derived-Modes.html:

> *Function: derived-mode-p &rest modes*
>
> This function returns non-nil if the current major mode is derived from
> any of the major modes given by the symbols modes.